# Guess the time format?

Tags: database, datetime, time

I have been given a list of times (shop opening hours) but the format seems really weird and doesn't seem to be any format that I can figure out and they didn't specify what format the time is in.

I'm guessing it's pulled straight form a database but doesn't seem to be seconds.

Example

> Opening time: 80000  (i'm assuming this is about 7:30 am in the morning )
>   Closing time: 170000 (i'm assuming this is about 9:00 pm)

Any guesses?

Comment: Our guesses are presumably as good as yours. This question is either too localized, not constructive, or both.

Comment: @djacobson there are only so many options mate.

Comment: I think you need to get more precise assumptions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it could just be 8 AM (8:00:00) to 5 PM (17:00:00). Probably the last two digits are seconds, the two to the left of those are minutes, and the remaining digits are hours, from 0 to 23.

Comment: yeah looks like that is probably the case